.join with a query
using .join I collect a string from the database
example:
print(f"{' '.join(str(conn.query(f'SELECT any_column from my_table WHERE id = 100')).split()[2:])}  \n")

needed to remove unnecessary first words from a string:
.split()[2:]
after I output the string collected after the join method, it always output only 4 words (regardless of the number of characters) and the first 2 letters of the next word
I get the following output: some example text to de...
But in database: some example text to demonstrate the error
How to fix?(get full output)
if you need anything else, I'll add it

Welcome to StackOverflow. What are the libraries involved with the provided code example? What is the actual error message and Traceback? The question as is contains insufficient details to reproduce the issue at hand. Without any way to guide others to reproduce the problem it becomes impossible to provide any answer. Please edit the question to include a minimal complete and verifiable example.  Also please refer to this guide on how to ask a question that may be answered.

Start by taking this apart step by step. Disentangle this unnecessary one-liner. Look at each value one by one. My bet would be on .query returning some result set object. When you cast this object to a string, it includes the abbreviated beginning of the result in it, but not the entire result. Because this result set isn't supposed to be the actual result, just an object that provides access to it. So you should probably properly get the result from that object, instead of doing a str() on it.

Fetch the department name from the database:
result = conn.query(f'SELECT department_name FROM view_personals WHERE id = {df_search.iloc[people].index[0]+1};')

Extract the department name from the result:
department_name = result[0]['department_name']

Write the full department name to the output
st.write(department_name)

